# Find number of consecutive different entries in a row for each entry

Tags: excel

I am attempting to automate a count showing how many consecutive different entries have been added in a row. For example, the first entry would return `1`, while the second entry would return `1` if the same as the first or `2` if different. I am struggling to find a way of getting the formula to search 'backwards' along the row until it finds an entry it has already seen.

I am struggling to find a way of getting the formula to search 'backwards' along the row until it finds an entry it has already seen.

The closest I have got (which very much does not work and is only half a formula) is something along the lines of `=IF(D2=C2,1,IF(COUNTIF($C2:D2,D2)=1,C6+1,""))` where the data is entered into row 2 starting in column B (the first two entries are trivial - it is after this I am struggling). The `""` within my formula is where I think that some clever checking will occur, but I can't work out what it would be.

My aim is that the following could be obtained:

```
A A B C D E F G H I A A A J K L B M N O A A A P A Q R A A 
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 9 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 8 1 1 2 2 3 4 3 1
```

However, my above formula only works until the run of 3x 'A's.

Many thanks for any help - this is my first question, so please be kind!

Comment: I think I've got an idea how to do it but it would be a rather ugly array formula, best look at it in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

1. type a `1` in cell `A2`
2. in cell `B2`, use the following formula:

   ```
   =IF(B1>A1,A2+1,1)
   ```
3. Populate this formula until the last column

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should be OK now, in A3:

```
=MIN(IF(COUNTIFS($A1:A1,$A1:A1,$A2:A2,">="&A2-TRANSPOSE($A2:A2)+1)>1,TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($A2:A2)),99)-1,COLUMNS($A1:A1))
```

It does require an extra row with numbers 1-29 in it.

Must be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

This starts off with the normal countif with an array. If you consider this for columns A-D, so COUNTIF($A1:D1,$A1:D1) you would get

```
2 2 1 1
```

(a row array) because of the repeated A's in A1 and B1.

I have used COUNTIFS and added another condition, to only take into account the current column (D), then add the column before it (C:D), then B:D and finally A:D. So you get a 2D array:

```
0 0 0 1

0 0 1 1

1 1 1 1 

2 2 1 1
```

Then substitute anything larger than 1 with a large number (say 99), anything else with the row number of the array:

```
99 99 99 99 
99 99 99 99 
99 99 99 99 
 4  4 99 99
```

Find the smallest number in the array and subtract 1.

If array contains all 99's,take the number of columns up to the current column.

Because Count and Countif only work with actual ranges, I couldn't think of a way of using them without creating a helper row containing the column numbers.